Braintree Vault app crash after complete whole process
Braintree paypal vault not working in flutter while accept aggrement.
Error log:

Process: com.thehandyx, PID: 9408 E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.thehandyx/com.braintreepayments.api.DropInActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.os.Bundle.setClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)' on a null
object reference E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4164)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) E/AndroidRuntime(
9408):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408):  at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9408): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.os.Bundle.setClassLoader(java.lang

